# Emails created with summernote are formatted differently when sent from Firefox and Chrome

Tags: php, summernote

I am trying to use summernote to send emails from a text editor. When the email is sent from Firefox, it is correctly formatted and matches the text entered in the text editor.

[Text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTMQI.jpg)
[Email received from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVSZU.jpg)

Code view in Firefox:

```
<span>Dear [OrderCustomerName],<br><br>Please click the link below to track your order.<br></span><div><span>[OrderTrackingURL] ONE</span></div><div><span>TWO</span></div><div><span><br></span></div><div><span>THREE<br></span></div><div><span></span></div>
```

However, if the same text is sent from Chrome, the formatting is broken.

[Email received from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckorg.jpg)

Code view in Chrome:

```
<span>Dear [OrderCustomerName],<br><br>Please click the link below to track your order.<br>[OrderTrackingURL] ONE</span><span>TWO</span><span><br></span><span>THREE</span>
```

I have prepared my summernote like this:

```
var height = 150;
$('#summernoteEmailBody').summernote({
    height: height,
    dialogsInBody: true,
    dialogsFade: true,
    toolbar: [
          ['style', ['style']],
          ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['fontname', ['fontname']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['table', ['table']],
          ['insert', ['link']],
          ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']],
    ],
}).on("summernote.enter", function(we, e) {
    $(this).summernote('pasteHTML', '');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Does anyone know why the summernote isn't adding all the extra divs and spans in Chrome, as it does in Firefox? I believe this is why the email is sending differently.

Comment: Are those "code views" directly inside summernote, when creating the message, or did you extract those from the emails received? In other words, what is the code in these stages: 1. Before you submit the summernote tekst, 2. as received on the server. 3. the email that was sent. 4. the email that was received. Finally, make sure you use exactly the same things for the last 2 steps.

Comment: The code views are accessed from pressing the </> button in the toolbar of the text editor (seen in the first attached image). This is generated before the email is sent, and I think this will match the code view of what is sent/received by email.

Comment: I tested my summernote in Firefox and Chrome, and I get `ONE</p><p>TWO</p><p><br></p><p>TRHEE<br></p>`, so no `<div>` or `<span>`. Let me see if I can find out why. Oh, I use the very latest version, that isn't even out yet, I build it myself from the sources.

Comment: I use the standard config, so I don't change anything. Nor do you, really. I cannot explain this. You could try to build a newer version yourself. Summernote uses Yarn.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately I cannot use the latest version of summernote for this project.

I'm currently using version v0.8.18

Comment: Well, you could still test v0.8.20, even if you cannot use it in your project, to see if that resolves the problem, then you know it is a version-dependent problem and not something else.

Comment: I tried with v0.8.20 and unfortunately the problem persists